# Create new column in R that adds 1 to the previous value just when criteria is met

Tags: r, tidyverse

I currently have a table ('cronograma') that looks like this:

[image]

I created the column "num" using the following code:

```
cronograma %>%
    mutate(num = ifelse(Situacao == lag(Situacao, 1), 1, 0))
```

However, what I really wanted to do was to add +1 every time that the value on "situacao" changed compared to the previous row.
In this case this would mean that from row 93 to 96, column "num" would be "1", from row 97 to  111 it would be "2", 112 to 117 it would be "3" and so on.

Is there any easy way to do this, preferably using tidyverse?

Thanks

Comment: `cumsum(Situacao != lag(Situacao, 1, default=""))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cumsum` and a negation (`!=`) will do what you want:

```r
cronograma %>%
  mutate(num = cumsum(Situacao != lag(Situacao, 1, default="")))
```